# MS EXCEL, SUMIFS() not returning intended value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble to use the following formula in excel to return the sum of value where the entry's date column falls within a defined range. It keeps return zero despite I have several entries that I believe match the condition.

```
=SUM((SUMIFS(Detail_Entries[Stby x1.0],Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)],Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)]>='New Report Template'!B1,Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)],Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)]<='New Report Template'!B2)))
```

The table is as follow

[image: Table containing the data]

Basically all it matters in this table for this formula is the "Date" column and the "Stby x1.0" column. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMIFS(Detail_Entries[Stby x1.0], Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)], ">="&'New Report Template'!B1, Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)], "<="&'New Report Template'!B2)
```

In this formula:

Detail_Entries[Stby x1.0] is the range you want to sum.
Detail_Entries[Date (yyyy/mm/dd)] is the range containing the dates.
">="&'New Report Template'!B1 specifies the condition that the date should be greater than or equal to the date in cell B1 of the 'New Report Template' sheet.
"<="&'New Report Template'!B2 specifies the condition that the date should be less than or equal to the date in cell B2 of the 'New Report Template' sheet.
Make sure the cell references in the formula match the location of your date range values. When you enter this corrected formula, it should give you the sum of values in the "Stby x1.0" column that fall within the specified date range.

Comment: Smells like GenAI.